# Connect SQL DB from remote html client

Tags: php, html, apache, mariadb

## Connect SQL DB from remote html client

### Server

I have a Debian server on which I created a really simple database :

```
MariaDB [data]> show columns from users;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| score | int(32)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

To access this database, I made a simple php code using w3school tutorials :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "mysqlUser";
$password = "***********";
$dbname = "data";

echo $servername . " , " . $username . " , " . $password . " , " . $dbname;

//echo $_POST["name"]."test";
//echo $_POST["score"];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO users(name, score)
VALUES ('John', '1234')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

And the insertion works just fine on the server. So I then made a really basic html form asking for a name and a score, and then calling the php file. I hosted this form with an Appach2 server.

### Client

When I access this server from a web browser I can fill the form, it is calling the php script as I see the first `echo` of the parameters, but the connection creation crashes.

html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Score: <input type="text" name="score"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I only have an internal error :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

But this is all new to me and I didn't find any "good"  tutorial to handle the database once everything is online. Maybe I'm not doing it the right way and shouldn't be using php, if you have any good resources I could look at or any idea why the connection isn't working it would be great !

Comment: So calling this exact script works from the browser, but calling this exact script from a form doesn't? That's weird, because this script doesn't do anything with user input (e.g. $_GET and $_POST), and should work the same in both scenarios. .. Unless the version that is failing is different from the version you posted..

Comment: No I'm just executing the php file on the server, but when I call it from the html form the insertion isn't working anymore

Comment: Can you show what code you used to access the php file... AJAX?

Comment: I would add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the code on both pages right at the top of the pages to see if there's an error being hidden by the 500 error. This can happen on production servers as you dont want anyone to know the error that's being encountered.

Comment: internal server error is just a generic error message displayed for security reasons. You need to switch on PHP error reporting as suggested above and find the real error message. That will tell you the source of your problem hopefully.

Comment: Great that's exactly the kind of "debug" or log I needed, thank you. I have this message now `Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/html/insert.php on line 15`

Comment: I would guess that the mysqli library is either not installed or not enabled in your server's PHP installation. You can google how to install/enable it for your specific O/S.